# ServiceNow REST API: return single column

Tags: servicenow

Is there a way to perform a REST call to ServiceNow REST API that returns a single column of a table? I would like to query the server table for only the names of the servers and not have the entire record containing some 50 plus fields returned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The latest REST Table API (as of Eureka, I think) supports the parameter `sysparm_fields`, which allows you to specify a comma-delimited list of fields to include in the response:

This URL template:

> https://YOURINSTANCENAME.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/incident?sysparm_fields=number,short_description,caller_id.name

Would give you a result with something like:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "caller_id.name": "",
      "short_description": "Unable to get to network file shares",
      "number": "INC0000002"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!